# how to start multi instances in one mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to deploy data slot to the distributed mysql databases via middleware，need one [mysql docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) container running two instances with different port, eg. 3306 and 3316.

tried many ways, such as:

1. Add **mysql_3316.sh**:

   `#!/bin/bash
   /entrypoint.sh --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my_3316.cnf`

   in the **rc.local**:

   `#!/bin/sh -e
   /usr/local/bin/mysql_3316.sh || exit 1
   exit 0`

   and modified the **Dockerfile** like below,

   `RUN touch /etc/mysql/my_3316.cnf
   COPY mysql_3316.sh /usr/local/bin/mysql_3316.sh
   RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mysql_3316.sh
   COPY rc.local /etc/rc.local
   RUN chmod +x /etc/rc.local
   RUN chown root:root /etc/rc.local
   ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
   EXPOSE 3306 3316
   CMD ["mysqld"]`

   it doesn't work while the mysql container comes up, but the `3316` mysql 
   port instance works by run the `/entrypoint.sh --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my_3316.cnf` shell line manually.
2. tried the **init.d** ,

   `RUN touch /etc/mysql/my_3316.cnf
   COPY mysql_3316.sh /etc/init.d/mysql_3316
   RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/mysql_3316
   RUN update-rc.d mysql_3316 defaults 99
   ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
   EXPOSE 3306 3316
   CMD ["mysqld"]`

   doesn't work too.
3. tried the **crontab**,

   `@reboot  /usr/local/bin/mysql_3316.sh
    #Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job`

   and the **Dockerfile** as that,

   `COPY mysql_3316.sh /usr/local/bin/mysql_3316.sh
   RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mysql_3316.sh
   ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/docker-cron
   RUN chmod +x /etc/cron.d/docker-cron
   RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/docker-cron
   ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
   EXPOSE 3306 3316
   CMD ["mysqld"]`

   doesn't work third.

It's been spent much on this key, almost give up...

Any kindly suggestion are welcomed please.

The `docker-compose.yml` for mysql right here:

```
services:
 mysql:
 image: mysql:latest
 container_name: mysql
 hostname: mysql
 restart: unless-stopped
 networks:
   dockernet:
     ipv4_address: 172.18.0.5
 ports:
   - 3306:3306
   - 3316:3316
 volumes:
   - /Docker/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
   - ./docker/mysql/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
   - ./docker/mysql/mysql/my_3316.cnf:/etc/mysql/my_3316.cnf
   - ./docker/mysql/mysql/logs/:/var/log/mysql/
   - ./docker/mysql/mysql/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
 entrypoint: ['/entrypoint.sh', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
```

Comment: This looks weird. Docker is used for microservices, why not using two instances of Docker ? [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a very usefull tool to make several containers communicate together. But I don't see the point with having two instances of MySQL in the same container

Comment: Yes, if two mysql works as master-master, if one node down, another one will stand double loads, otherwise if spread the full load to two instances on different node, the load will be half. That's the point.

Comment: How exactly can the load be half if both instances are on a different node?

Comment: Some database middleware can separate the read and write queue to different sql service, in my case, is designed to mysql A 3306 port service will be the master-master of the mysql B  3316 service, and B 3306 port will be the master-master of the C 3316 service ...； so if B down,  the A 3306 and the C 3316 will take over the Full B load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the stock `mysql` container and just run:

```sh
docker run -p3306:3306 --name mysql1 mysql
docker run -p3316:3306 --name mysql2 mysql
# plus appropriate -d -e ... -v ... as needed on both commands
```

Don't try to build your own image and definitely don't try to run two servers with expected different lifetimes in a single container.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. Docker deployment on the productions environment is new for me, maybe some new technology such as k8s can handle mass of nodes and instances very well, although less chance  to close to practice it. Will keep attention. Thanks again, for your experienced pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you do NOT want to run more than one process in the same container. Despite your title I really think that what you are looking for is to start two containers, both from a MySQL image.

You should not need to change any startup scripts, Dockerfile or anything else to start up similar containers bound to different ports.

Remember that the `EXPOSE` command only exposes the ports to different containers, not to the outside world.

To access the port you need to use the `-p` flag with your `docker run`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

You can use the same docker image from the same Dockerfile. Just give different `-p` parameter when you run.

Edit:
You added your docker-compose.yml after my initial response. Using docker-compose will make my advice about `-p` obsolete, and you should use the `ports:` section of the docker-compose.yml to vary the port numbers instead.

This answer, however, might not be what you are looking for because based on your comment I think I do not fully understand your use case here.

Comment: -v? volume?
Thanks your reply.

I used the two instance with two ports in one mysql server very well in real environment before, for if one node down, it's full load will spread to two nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `-p`. Editing

Comment: Based on your comment I think I might not be entirely understanding your use case here. I thought you wanted two mysql servers? If one node of what goes down?

Comment: The question showed just the one container to startup two instances test, the past running environment has six master-master mysql server totally twelve master server , and five databases each one, to distribute  the data slots.